# MySQL right join is order of magnitude faster for counting

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance, outer-join

Having two tables, `products` and `submissions`, both with around 1 million records and fully indexed, I want to count the elements based on a condition. However, even counting the basic result of join is very slow.

The tables have a 1-1 relationship, with `submissions` having `product_id` foreign key. See the following 4 queries:

```sql
select count(*)
from products P 
join submissions S on S.product_id=P.id 
# Takes 2 seconds
```

And explain on that query:

```
1   SIMPLE  S   index   submissions_product_id_foreign  submissions_product_id_foreign  4   NULL    776660  Using index
1   SIMPLE  P   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   ma_prod.S.product_id    1   Using index
```

However, running the following query:

```sql
select count(*)
from products P 
RIGHT join submissions S on S.product_id=P.id
```

Takes 300 ms. The explain is also different:

```
1   SIMPLE  S   index   NULL    submissions_product_id_foreign  4   NULL    776662  Using index
```

I can't wrap my head around what is happening. Both queries have the same result and do the same join, so why is one skipping a `eq_ref` operation? Besides, the `eq_ref` is supposed to be super fast on the foreign key.

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what's happening. You can swap the tables and instead use LEFT JOIN, same results.

Comment: Good plan. :-).

Comment: Are the results different?  If so, you cannot use one formulation in place of the other.

Comment: Right outer joins are less common, but it's an exaggeration to say they are _never_ used. See https://www.quora.com/Database-Systems-What-are-the-differences-between-a-left-join-and-a-right-join/answer/Bill-Karwin

Comment: Are you sure the second EXPLAIN is for the query shown? It should have two rows, one for `S` and one for `P`. An EXPLAIN will always have a row for each table reference, so in a query that joins two tables, there should be two rows.

Comment: You write, "See the following 4 queries" but you only show 2 queries with their EXPLAIN. I'm not sure you have shared all the information you intended to share.

Comment: Explain is a query itself.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL documentation for `JOIN` is pretty dense, but one fun thing it says is:

> STRAIGHT_JOIN is similar to JOIN, except that the left table is always
> read before the right table. This can be used for those (few) cases
> for which the join optimizer processes the tables in a suboptimal
> order.

And for your query, `RIGHT JOIN` convinces the optimizer to read the right table before the left table, which is better. Take each submission and find the single product it goes with using a primary key - vs take each product and find the multiple submissions that go with it, even using an index. The latter approach obviously iterates over the table more times.

I think you are basically dealing with a bug, or weakness if you prefer, in the join optimizer and that's it. Sometimes MySQL still needs the brilliant DBA's help to run a query in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

`RIGHT` and `LEFT` `JOINs` say that the presence of one of the tables (the left or right, respectively) is optional.

Normally, left or right is used when you want `NULLs` for missing data, or to discover missing rows.  But you are doing neither.

You are asking for how many submissions there are, and not really caring about whether there is a matching `product`.  And the Optimizer realized that `product` was useless and threw it away when designing the query execution.

So, it is faster.  But probably has a different `COUNT(*)`.

So, do you want it "fast" or do you want it "correct"?